# How to make a gift ribbon in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to make a ribbon for a gift box (normal cubegeometry) in three.js like this one for example:

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_a1luqIHQT68/SVQ3aeo5SKI/AAAAAAAAAAk/SzCYXD9Df1Y/s400/Geschenk-neu.jpg

is there a method for this and is it possible to make it out of just one ribbon or do i need more than one, which add up to this big one?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just for show and you don't need it programmatically, I suggest loading a premade blender/json model from a file.

Source example: http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Model.html

here are some free models: http://archive3d.net/?tag=present

Comment: i would like to animate it, that it changes it position after some seconds

Comment: I guess that would be a bit harder.. Good luck :)